# Can Solr DIH create multiple documents instead of using multiValued?

Tags: json, solr

In the examples for the DIH that come with Solr 5.2.1, they have a db example that uses items, item_categories, and categories. Since an item can belong to multiple categories, is there a way to get it to create a document per category, rather than a document per item and using multiValued fields to hold the multiple categories? Or would I have to make my own data import handler to do this?

I know I could accomplish what I want by generating the JSON first and submitting a JSON document for each item/category combination, but it would be nice to be able to leverage the delta query functionality of the DIH.

Comment: Why does multiValued field not work for you? You can still facet on it and everything. In general, yes, anything is possible, you just need the right SQL query and then DIH will map it one-to-one with the correct definition.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, I guess I just figured it would make more sense to have one result document per row in the query that I wrote. I have only been experimenting with Solr for about a week so I'm still quite new. Perhaps instead of nested queries I could use one query with all the joins?

Comment: This is a more generic question, but usually you want to think backwards from the results you want to display. Then you map your internal representation to make that result easier.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a good idea the more I familiarize myself with how it works.